# How do I alter CAS configuration to use (email,password) authentication?

Tags: authentication, configuration, liferay, cas

How do I alter CAS configuration to use (email,password) authentication for users in liferay rather than the default email verification used by CAS server?

```
**2012-02-23 07:35:22,659 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - <Loaded 4 services.>
2012-02-23 07:35:22,815 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - <Context initialization failed>
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler#f3941' of type [org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler] while setting bean property 'authenticationHandlers' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler] for bean with name 'org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler#f3941' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized_aroundBody0(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:62)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized_aroundBody1$advice(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:1)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:964)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler#f3941' of type [org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler] while setting bean property 'authenticationHandlers' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler] for bean with name 'org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler#f3941' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler] for bean with name 'org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler#f3941' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:433)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1242)
    ... 56 more**
```

Answer (score 1):

To use Liferay user table with email and password fields, you should change the following fragment of the CAS `deployerConfigContext.xml`:

```xml
    <property name="authenticationHandlers">
                <list> 
                        <!-- | This is the authentication handler that authenticates services by
  means of callback via SSL, thereby validating | a server side SSL certificate. + -->
                        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler" p:httpClient-ref="httpClient"></bean>
                        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler">
                                <property name="tableUsers">
                                        <value>User_</value>
                                </property>
                                <property name="fieldUser">
                                        <value>emailAddress</value>
                                </property>
                                <property name="fieldPassword">
                                        <value>password_</value>
                                </property>
                                <property name="passwordEncoder">
                                        <bean class="com.ccm.ci.cas.authentication.handler.LiferayPasswordEncoder">
                                                <!-- Default Liferay Password Encryption is SHA algorithm. If someone changes it in liferay it have to been changed here-->
                                                <constructor-arg name="encodingAlgorithm" value="SHA"></constructor-arg>
                                        </bean>
                                </property>
                                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
                        </bean>
                </list>
        </property>
```

AND

[customize CAS](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Maintaining+local+customizations+using+Maven+2) with the following class to decode Liferay 6 encoded password (see the password encoder property in the above fragment).

```java
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.PasswordEncoder;
import org.vps.crypt.Crypt;
/**
 * To authenticate cas over Liferay 6.0.5 database using liferay 6.0.5 hashing
 * algorithms.
 * 
 */
public class LiferayPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {

    public static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";

    public static final String TYPE_CRYPT = "CRYPT";

    public static final String TYPE_MD2 = "MD2";

    public static final String TYPE_MD5 = "MD5";

    public static final String TYPE_NONE = "NONE";

    public static final String TYPE_SHA = "SHA";

    public static final String TYPE_SHA_256 = "SHA-256";

    public static final String TYPE_SHA_384 = "SHA-384";

    public static final String TYPE_SSHA = "SSHA";

    public static final DigesterImpl digesterImpl = new DigesterImpl();

    @NotNull
    private static String PASSWORDS_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = TYPE_SHA;

    public LiferayPasswordEncoder() {
    }

    public LiferayPasswordEncoder(final String encodingAlgorithm) {

        PASSWORDS_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = encodingAlgorithm;

    }

    public static final char[] saltChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789./"
            .toCharArray();

    public static String encrypt(String clearTextPassword) {

        return encrypt(PASSWORDS_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM, clearTextPassword, null);
    }

    public static String encrypt(String clearTextPassword,
            String currentEncryptedPassword) {

        return encrypt(PASSWORDS_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM, clearTextPassword,
                currentEncryptedPassword);
    }

    public static String encrypt(String algorithm, String clearTextPassword,
            String currentEncryptedPassword) {

        if (algorithm.equals(TYPE_CRYPT)) {
            byte[] saltBytes = _getSaltFromCrypt(currentEncryptedPassword);

            return encodePassword(algorithm, clearTextPassword, saltBytes);
        } else if (algorithm.equals(TYPE_NONE)) {
            return clearTextPassword;
        } else if (algorithm.equals(TYPE_SSHA)) {
            byte[] saltBytes = _getSaltFromSSHA(currentEncryptedPassword);

            return encodePassword(algorithm, clearTextPassword, saltBytes);
        } else {
            return encodePassword(algorithm, clearTextPassword, null);
        }
    }

    protected static String encodePassword(String algorithm,
            String clearTextPassword, byte[] saltBytes) {

        try {
            if (algorithm.equals(TYPE_CRYPT)) {
                return Crypt.crypt(saltBytes, clearTextPassword.getBytes(UTF8));
            } else if (algorithm.equals(TYPE_SSHA)) {
                byte[] clearTextPasswordBytes = clearTextPassword
                        .getBytes(UTF8);

                // Create a byte array of salt bytes appeneded to password bytes

                byte[] pwdPlusSalt = new byte[clearTextPasswordBytes.length
                        + saltBytes.length];

                System.arraycopy(clearTextPasswordBytes, 0, pwdPlusSalt, 0,
                        clearTextPasswordBytes.length);

                System.arraycopy(saltBytes, 0, pwdPlusSalt,
                        clearTextPasswordBytes.length, saltBytes.length);

                // Digest byte array

                MessageDigest sha1Digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

                byte[] pwdPlusSaltHash = sha1Digest.digest(pwdPlusSalt);

                // Appends salt bytes to the SHA-1 digest.

                byte[] digestPlusSalt = new byte[pwdPlusSaltHash.length
                        + saltBytes.length];

                System.arraycopy(pwdPlusSaltHash, 0, digestPlusSalt, 0,
                        pwdPlusSaltHash.length);

                System.arraycopy(saltBytes, 0, digestPlusSalt,
                        pwdPlusSaltHash.length, saltBytes.length);

                // Base64 encode and format string

                return Base64.encode(digestPlusSalt);
            } else {
                return digesterImpl.digest(algorithm, clearTextPassword);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
            throw new SecurityException("LiferayPasswordEncryption error:"
                    + nsae.getMessage(), nsae);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new SecurityException("LiferayPasswordEncryption error:"
                    + uee.getMessage(), uee);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] _getSaltFromCrypt(String cryptString) {

        byte[] saltBytes = null;

        try {
            if (Validator.isNull(cryptString)) {

                // Generate random salt

                Random random = new Random();

                int numSaltChars = saltChars.length;

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                int x = random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numSaltChars;
                int y = random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numSaltChars;

                sb.append(saltChars[x]);
                sb.append(saltChars[y]);

                String salt = sb.toString();

                saltBytes = salt.getBytes(Digester.ENCODING);
            } else {

                // Extract salt from encrypted password

                String salt = cryptString.substring(0, 2);

                saltBytes = salt.getBytes(Digester.ENCODING);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new SecurityException(
                    "Unable to extract salt from encrypted password: "
                            + uee.getMessage(), uee);
        }

        return saltBytes;
    }

    private static byte[] _getSaltFromSSHA(String sshaString) {

        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[8];

        if (Validator.isNull(sshaString)) {

            // Generate random salt

            Random random = new SecureRandom();

            random.nextBytes(saltBytes);
        } else {

            // Extract salt from encrypted password

            try {
                byte[] digestPlusSalt = Base64.decode(sshaString);
                byte[] digestBytes = new byte[digestPlusSalt.length - 8];

                System.arraycopy(digestPlusSalt, 0, digestBytes, 0,
                        digestBytes.length);

                System.arraycopy(digestPlusSalt, digestBytes.length, saltBytes,
                        0, saltBytes.length);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new SecurityException(
                        "Unable to extract salt from encrypted password: "
                                + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

        return saltBytes;
    }

    public String encode(String pwd) {
        return encrypt(pwd);
    }

}
```

---

FINALLY add the following Liferay portal classes (you can found them in Liferay portal sources) to the customized CAS (they are used by the above LiferayPasswordEncoder):

Base64.java

CharPool.java

ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java

Digester.java

DigesterImpl.java

StringBundler.java

StringPool.java

UnsyncByteArrayInputStream.java

UnsyncByteArrayOutputStream.java

Validator.java

---

EDIT: added complete `deployerConfigContext.xml` for the error and CAS version question:

I'm running CAS version 3.4.5, and you?

Here it is my complete deployerConfigContext.xml file. I think there is some error in your file introduced while adding the fragment above. In fact the missing bean is defined in that file. Please try to merge the following file with your (given the differences in database url, username and password, etc..):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- | deployerConfigContext.xml centralizes into one file some of the declarative
  configuration that | all CAS deployers will need to modify. | | This file declares
  some of the Spring-managed JavaBeans that make up a CAS deployment. | The beans declared
  in this file are instantiated at context initialization time by the Spring | ContextLoaderListener
  declared in web.xml. It finds this file because this | file is among those declared
  in the context parameter "contextConfigLocation". | | By far the most common change
  you will need to make in this file is to change the last bean | declaration to replace
  the default SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler with | one implementing
  your approach for authenticating usernames and passwords. + -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="propertyPlaceholder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"></property>
    </bean>
    <!-- | This bean declares our AuthenticationManager. The CentralAuthenticationService
    service bean | declared in applicationContext.xml picks up this AuthenticationManager
    by reference to its id, | "authenticationManager". Most deployers will be able to
    use the default AuthenticationManager | implementation and so do not need to change
    the class of this bean. We include the whole | AuthenticationManager here in the
    userConfigContext.xml so that you can see the things you will | need to change in
    context. + -->
    <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl">
        <!-- | This is the List of CredentialToPrincipalResolvers that identify what
      Principal is trying to authenticate. | The AuthenticationManagerImpl considers them
      in order, finding a CredentialToPrincipalResolver which | supports the presented
      credentials. | | AuthenticationManagerImpl uses these resolvers for two purposes.
      First, it uses them to identify the Principal | attempting to authenticate to CAS
      /login . In the default configuration, it is the DefaultCredentialsToPrincipalResolver
      | that fills this role. If you are using some other kind of credentials than UsernamePasswordCredentials,
      you will need to replace | DefaultCredentialsToPrincipalResolver with a CredentialsToPrincipalResolver
      that supports the credentials you are | using. | | Second, AuthenticationManagerImpl
      uses these resolvers to identify a service requesting a proxy granting ticket. |
      In the default configuration, it is the HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver
      that serves this purpose. | You will need to change this list if you are identifying
      services by something more or other than their callback URL. + -->
        <property name="credentialsToPrincipalResolvers">
            <list>
                <!-- | UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports the UsernamePasswordCredentials
          that we use for /login | by default and produces SimplePrincipal instances conveying
          the username from the credentials. | | If you've changed your LoginFormAction to
          use credentials other than UsernamePasswordCredentials then you will also | need
          to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations) to declare a CredentialsToPrincipalResolver
          that supports the | Credentials you are using. + -->
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver"></bean>
                <!-- | HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports HttpBasedCredentials.
          It supports the CAS 2.0 approach of | authenticating services by SSL callback, extracting
          the callback URL from the Credentials and representing it as a | SimpleService identified
          by that callback URL. | | If you are representing services by something more or other
          than an HTTPS URL whereat they are able to | receive a proxy callback, you will need
          to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations). + -->
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver"></bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- | Whereas CredentialsToPrincipalResolvers identify who it is some Credentials
      might authenticate, | AuthenticationHandlers actually authenticate credentials. Here
      we declare the AuthenticationHandlers that | authenticate the Principals that the
      CredentialsToPrincipalResolvers identified. CAS will try these handlers in turn |
      until it finds one that both supports the Credentials presented and succeeds in authenticating.
      + -->
        <property name="authenticationHandlers">
            <list>
                <!-- | This is the authentication handler that authenticates services by
          means of callback via SSL, thereby validating | a server side SSL certificate. + -->
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler" p:httpClient-ref="httpClient"></bean>
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler">
                    <property name="tableUsers">
                        <value>User_</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="fieldUser">
                        <value>emailAddress</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="fieldPassword">
                        <value>password_</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="passwordEncoder">
                        <bean class="com.ccm.ci.cas.authentication.handler.LiferayPasswordEncoder">
                            <!-- Default Liferay Password Encryption is SHA algorithm. If someone changes it in liferay it have to been changed here-->
                            <constructor-arg name="encodingAlgorithm" value="SHA"></constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- This bean defines the security roles for the Services Management application.
    Simple deployments can use the in-memory version. More robust deployments will want
    to use another option, such as the Jdbc version. The name of this should remain "userDetailsService"
    in order for Spring Security to find it. -->
    <!-- <sec:user name="@@THIS SHOULD BE REPLACED@@" password="notused" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"
    /> -->
    <sec:user-service id="userDetailsService">
        <sec:user name="@@THIS SHOULD BE REPLACED@@" password="notused" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"></sec:user>
    </sec:user-service>
    <!-- Bean that defines the attributes that a service may return. This example uses
    the Stub/Mock version. A real implementation may go against a database or LDAP server.
    The id should remain "attributeRepository" though. -->
    <bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.StubPersonAttributeDao">
        <property name="backingMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="uid" value="uid"></entry>
                <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation"></entry>
                <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership"></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Sample, in-memory data store for the ServiceRegistry. A real implementation
    would probably want to replace this with the JPA-backed ServiceRegistry DAO The name
    of this bean should remain "serviceRegistryDao". -->
    <bean id="serviceRegistryDao" class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl">
        <property name="registeredServices">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl">
                    <property name="id" value="0"></property>
                    <property name="name" value="HTTP"></property>
                    <property name="description" value="Only Allows HTTP Urls"></property>
                    <property name="serviceId" value="http://**"></property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl">
                    <property name="id" value="1"></property>
                    <property name="name" value="HTTPS"></property>
                    <property name="description" value="Only Allows HTTPS Urls"></property>
                    <property name="serviceId" value="https://**"></property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl">
                    <property name="id" value="2"></property>
                    <property name="name" value="IMAPS"></property>
                    <property name="description" value="Only Allows HTTPS Urls"></property>
                    <property name="serviceId" value="imaps://**"></property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl">
                    <property name="id" value="3"></property>
                    <property name="name" value="IMAP"></property>
                    <property name="description" value="Only Allows IMAP Urls"></property>
                    <property name="serviceId" value="imap://**"></property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Data source definition -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://10.4.2.14:3306/lportal_${user.name}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>${user.name}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${user.name}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="initialSize" value="1"></property>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5"></property>
        <property name="maxActive" value="50"></property>
        <property name="maxWait" value="10000"></property>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1"></property>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false"></property>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"></property>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000"></property>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="30000"></property>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="-1"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: :It is showing message                                          Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager'

Comment: I'm CAS version 3.4.8.After updating the deployerconfigContext.xml,still this error is displayed Error creating bean with name 'auditTrailManagementAspect' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/auditTrailContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'auditTrailManager' while setting constructor argument with key [0];

Comment: This is a different error. I don't have the auditTrailManager.xml because it is the spring bean config file about auditing and has been introduced after 3.4.5. So if you copied and not merged my posted deployerConfigContext.xml (3.4.5 version) than I think the following bean declaration (new from 3.4.7) has been removed:
<bean id="auditTrailManager" class="com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager" /> 
See http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jasig.cas.user/17197

Comment: thanks for the further changes..I had just copied it rather than merging it so that error is gone,but now the previous error(error creating bean) is again showing up.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the entire stack trace of the exception? (My hypothesis is that the root cause are some missing classes used by LiferayPasswordEncoder)

Comment: I have updated the question to include the entire stack trace.Also let me know of any addtional jar dependencies for the LiferayPasswordEncoder class,as Digester and Validator class methods showed some compiler errors too.Thanks a lot

Comment: I added the list of classes used by LiferayPasswordEncoder, you can found them in Liferay portal sources.